# How can I change the framerate settings in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, frame-rate

At home, when I run all of my programs, by default run at a maximum of 60 fps (I use the show FPS to see it as the program runs).

However, I have just transferred the program to my laptop. Now the program runs at a maximum of 30 FPS by default (deleting all the code so that it does nothing didn't make a difference)

Please can someone help me find the relevant setting on Xcode to fix this? Thanks

Comment: is this in the simulator?  are you sure your laptop is just not fast enough to handle the FPS

Comment: Deleting all the code doesn't change the 30 FPS..

Comment: but the simulator itself may not be able to run at 60 FPS

Comment: My apologies - I thought I had specified above, but I hadn't. The simulator on my laptop can run at 60 FPS, and this is the case when the window takes up about 1/4 of the screen. However, it can only do 30 FPS for some reason at full screen size. This is not the case with my desktop at home.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly,  when the simulator is 1/4 of your screen on your laptop, it can run at 60FPS,  if it is full screen on your laptop, then it runs 30FPS.  If this is the case, then your laptop is too old for the simulator that you are currently running, time to upgrade I guess.  BTW what is your laptop

Comment: Well I guess you are right then. My laptop is old... several years. I'm not 100% sure on the model, but it is a MacBookPro, I think. I was worried about this issue, because I have not yet tried to run any of my programs on an actual iDevice - and I thought that iDevices may have an even lower quality of performance than the laptop, meaning I would have to change my program. Would this be the case?

Comment: No,  your machine has to do a lot of extra work to simulate the iphone environment,  it will run a lot faster at the hardware level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, when the simulator is 1/4 of your screen on your laptop, it can run at 60FPS, if it is full screen on your laptop, then it runs 30FPS. If this is the case, then your laptop is too old for the simulator that you are currently running, time to upgrade I guess

Your machine has to do a lot of extra work to simulate the iphone environment, it will run a lot faster at the hardware level

Comment: Ok thanks. (The machine currently isn't simulating the iPhone, btw - I have yet to do that conversion, but I expect the answer will be the same)

Comment: oh you are writing Mac OSX apps?   when you said iDevice I figured you using iPhone / iPad,  and I just called it iphone environment,  but yes the results would be the same

Comment: I am currently writing for Mac OS X, but actually, I will switch platform to iOS once the apps are finished. (I just simply prefer to make programs this way)

Comment: That is fine,  I have not done a lot of Mac OSX development so I couldnt tell you if the simulator is different in speed then when executed,  but I do know that it is different for iOS